# Jquery: image Loader position and hiding mess up

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got a modal dialog that pop up then load and show the loader image then after a seconds it will hide and preview the "modalLogin" page.

At first loading the main page and clicking  the button for modal dialog to pop up it is fine, but when I close the modal dialog and click the button for modal again, the loading is mess up! So can anyone explain to me what is wrong?

```
  $(href).fadeIn(100, function(){
                $('#loadingImage').show(1,function(){

                     setTimeout( function(){
                         $('#loadingImage').hide(1,
                             function(){

                            if(thisId == 'loginModal' ){
                                $('#previewOutput').load('modalLogin.php');
                                //alert("Login");
                            }
                         }
                  );                             

                     },500);

                });

            });
```

Here the link : http://jsfiddle.net/UZ6JN/1/

Comment: Your fiddle works for me - clicking share opens the window with a short spinning animation - close and reopen works fine

Comment: yeah it is working fine but the when you close the modal and click the share again it is mess up. But it is okay now. Just gonna put hide on the #previewOutput

Answer (score 2):

Its because when you put text with `.html()` it stays there, if you want to see correctly then add one line in this:

```
 $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
     //Cancel the link behavior
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#previewOutput').html(''); //<--------add this one here
     $('#mask').hide();
     $('.window').hide();
 });
```

[**check this out in fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/UZ6JN/2/)